# nginx server response packet capture

Tags: nginx

I wrote a tool which will display the trace of all the http request type (GET,POST..) that the nginx server has received and the responses(200,404..) sent for that request.
 Now I want to increase its capability by  displaying the request body and response body . 
I was able to capture the request body and dump it on to access.log file .
I am stuck in capturing the response body. 
how do i achieve this ?
I want to write the response body to some log file.
thank you .

Comment: Didn't you just invent tcpdump/wireshark/etc?

Comment: thanks alexey, what u suggested works good in debugging n viewing the response body . but how can i add this into my trace tool?